# ORMLite Date in MySQL/MariaDB with millisecond precision

Tags: ormlite, mariadb

ORMLite question. I have a set of POJOs that are used by both an Android app and a Java web service to persist data (to SQLite and MariaDB, respectively). Since 5.3, I believe, MariaDB supports timestamps/datetimes with a length, which expands the precision of the field to microseconds (MySQL itself is supporting this in the new dev 5.6 release).

However, I haven't been able to get ORMLite to persist my Date field with millisecond precision, even if I manually modify the field from the command line to set the column to DATETIME(6). I understand I could use a dataType of DATE_LONG or DATE_STRING in the POJO, but I'd like to use the actual DATETIME type in MariaDB.

Is there any way I can do this with millisecond precision?

Comment: So this is with the MySQL driver?  You may have to add a custom data type: http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-data-types

Comment: Ah, your question made me realize the issue. MariaDB now actually has their own JDBC java client (they oddly suggest that you still format the connection URI as jdbc:mysql://). Because of how DatabaseTypeUtils is structured, I can't add a BaseDatabaseType subclass for the MariaDB driver...so I'm stuck using the MySQL Connector one. What would be really cool is if users could create their own BaseDatabaseType subclass, and there'd be a static setter for databaseTypes on DatabaseTypeUtils to load it (granted, I recognize you have all the major DBs covered-but MariaDB will only get more popular)!

Comment: Ok, I was clearly being stupid...you support passing in a databaseType when you start a new JdbcConnectionSource / JdbcPooledConnectionSource. So I simply subclassed the MysqlDatabaseType and did what I needed to do. I'll put the code below. Also, for any users who might actually be trying to solve this exact issue, you need to set the useFractionalSeconds flag in the JDBC connection string. Grey - thanks for responding so quickly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out Matt. +1 on your question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a the comments under the question to understand what's happening here...basically you need a new DatabaseType (if working with MariaDB, then obviously just subclass the MySQL one):

```
public class MariaDBType extends MysqlDatabaseType {

    private final static String DATABASE_URL_PORTION = "mysql";
    private final static String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver";
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MariaDB";

    @Override
    public boolean isDatabaseUrlThisType(String url, String dbTypePart) {
        return DATABASE_URL_PORTION.equals(dbTypePart);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDriverClassName() {
        return DRIVER_CLASS_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return DATABASE_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendDateType(StringBuilder sb, FieldType fieldType, int fieldWidth) {
        /**
         * TIMESTAMP in MySQL does some funky stuff with the last-modification time. Values are 'not null' by default
         * with an automatic default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Strange design decision.
         */
        if (isDatetimeFieldWidthSupported()) {
            sb.append("DATETIME(").append(fieldWidth).append(")");
        } else {
            sb.append("DATETIME");
        }
    }

    public boolean isDatetimeFieldWidthSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I can use the date dataType like normal and get millisecond or microsecond precision...in my case, I used Gray's existing annotation param for width (good for a case like this, where I only need millisecond precision, not microseconds).

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = Constants.TIMESTAMP, dataType = DataType.DATE, width = 3)
private Date timestamp;
```

Finally, if you're trying to solve this specific issue, don't forget the fractional seconds flag:

```
private static JdbcPooledConnectionSource cSource = new JdbcPooledConnectionSource();
    cSource.setDatabaseType(new MariaDBType());
    cSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useFractionalSeconds=true");
    cSource.setUsername("username");
    cSource.setPassword("password");
```

Comment: This is a great answer Matt.  Well done.  Gives all of the information necessary for others to do what you did.